# Using Import and Require in the same NodeJS project

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, es6-modules, commonjs

I have a Node.js project whose modules are imported in the Common.JS way using `require`. However, the need arose to import a package that is ESM only.

One way to use ESM `import from` in my project was to add `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` file. However, all the `requires` stoped working.

I verified that one solution would be to create the require module from the `module` package:

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

However, the entire (large) project has imports with `require` and it seems to me unfeasible to have to add this solution to each one of them.

So I'd like to know if there's an elegant way to declare `require` just once and have it be used throughout the project.

Or, is there any more elegant solution than creating the `require` or substituting everything for ESM?

Answer (score 0):

To use `require` and `import` together, you need to use dynamic `import()` expressions to load an ES module into a CommonJS context.

A common Node.js error message that provides a solution looks like this:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module <path> from <path> not supported.
Instead change the require of <path> in <path> to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Here is an example of using `lodash` and `lodash-es`:

```js
const lodash = require('lodash')

async function main() {
  const output = lodash.concat(['hello'], ['world'])
  const lodashEs = await import('lodash-es')

  console.log(lodashEs.join(output, ' '))
}

main()
```